# Windows 10 - WiFi doesn't have a valid IP configuration

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, wifi-configuration

Yesterday, seemingly at random, after a restart, my WiFi dropped out. After troubleshooting I was given the error I've written in the title of this thread.

I did some googling and tried the following:

1. Reset TCP/IP
2. Checked my channel width set to auto (it is)
3. Manually set my IP address
4. Rolled back WiFi adapter drivers
5. Removed my anti virus software and turned off windows firewall (just to test)

Nothing I've tried has worked, when I hover over the WiFi icon in my taskbar it states 'unidentified network - no Internet access'

Can anyone help? I have no idea what else to do besides reformat!

Comment: Reboot the router, then the puter again.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that was the first thing I tried.

Comment: OK, sometimes the obvious gets missed ;)

Comment: Sounds like “gateway” isn’t defined or is not correct.  It’s unclear if you’ve undone “manually set my IP address”.  Assuming your routers DHCP server is turned on, go back to “set automatically” or “use DHCP” and then reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue but with LAN. What I did:

1. Deleted all LAN drivers (Device Manager->Delete LAN hardware).
2. Open RegEdit
3. Open key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Adapters
4. Delete all subkeys
5. Open key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces
6. Delete  all subkeys.
7. Reboot.

After that Windows reinstalled drivers and all now works fine.

Comment: Never delete registry keys in that registry path. IP configuration and NIC devices will loose their configuration. Even network may not work.

Comment: That is the goal that NIC looses config.